# How can I permanently change system limits in Mojave (OSX 10.14)?

Tags: macos, operating-systems, macos-mojave

How do you change the system limits for MacOS Mojave? I need to increase the open-file limit.

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice guide on that [here](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/deep-dive/evade-macos-many-open-files-error-pushing-limits/)

Basically you have to disable `SIP` (System Integrity Protection) and then edit

```
sudo vim /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist
```

with the following payload

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
 "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0"> 
 <dict>
 <key>Label</key>
 <string>limit.maxfiles</string>
 <key>ProgramArguments</key>
 <array>
 <string>launchctl</string>
 <string>limit</string>
 <string>maxfiles</string>
 <string>64000</string>
 <string>524288</string>
 </array>
 <key>RunAtLoad</key>
 <true/>
 <key>ServiceIPC</key>
 <false/>
 </dict>
</plist>
```

Please note the two numbers there and adjust to your needs